# Javascript | Pass an objects function as argument into another object

Tags: javascript, object, methods, p5.js

I'm currently building a GUI in javascript, and I want to be able to pass one objects function as an argument to another object, the code below demonstrates the problem and the expected output.

```
var Window = function(){
    this.close = function(){
        console.log(this)
    }
}


var Button = function(func){
    this.func = func;
    this.press = function(){
        this.func();
    }
}

var win = new Window();
var button = new Button(win.close);

button.press();
//Output: Button object
//Expected output: Window object
```

Comment: You should bind win.close to window. 
Which means do this: `win.close.bind(win)`. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: You can also use an arrow function `var button = new Button(() => win.close());`

Answer (score 3):

You should bind the function to the object you want `this` to reference. Check this MDN reference for how to use [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```js
var Window = function(){
    
    this.close = function(){
        console.log(this)
    }
    this.close = this.close.bind(this)
}


var Button = function(func){
    this.func = func;
    this.press = function(){
        this.func();
    }
}

var win = new Window();
var button = new Button(win.close);

button.press();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var Button = function(func){
    //this.func = func; this is not required.
    this.press = function(){
       func(); //just call func
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Window = function(){
    var w = {};
    w.close = function(){
        console.log(w);
    }
    return w;
}


var Button = function(func){
    var b = {press: func};
    return b;
}

var win = new Window();
var button = new Button(win.close);

button.press();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference like this:

```js
var Window = function(){
    var context= this;
    this.close = function(){
        console.log(context)
        //output: Object { close: Window/this.close() }
    }
}


var Button = function(func){
    this.func = func;
    this.press = function(){
        this.func();
    }
}

var win = new Window();
var button = new Button(win.close);

button.press();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass outer 'this' to be passed to press() as a different variable like I shown in below. I assigned 'this' to 'self' and I referenced it in the press(). That is the only change I made to your code.

```
var Window = function(){
  this.close = function(){
    console.log(this)
  }
}


var Button = function(func){
   let self = this;      // this is the change I made
   this.func = func;
   this.press = function(){
     self.func();        // this is the change I made
  }
}

var win = new Window();
var button = new Button(win.close);

button.press();
```